# dynamic cast a reference and auto

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, auto, dynamic-cast

I've encountered a pretty weird behavior when using auto and dynamic_cast.
This is the class hierachy i have:

```
class BaseInterface {
public:
    virtual void someMethod()=0;
};

class Derived:public BaseInterface {
public:
    virtual void someMethod1()=0;
    void someMethod()override;
};
```

And of course there are some classes that implement all derived methods.

Then there is a third class which looks like this:

```
class ThirdClass {
public:
    void demoMethod(BaseInterface&);
    void anotherMethod(Derived&);
};

void ThirdClass::demoMethod(BaseInterface& obj) {
    auto buffer=dynamic_cast<Derived&>(obj);
    anotherMethod(buffer);
}
```

When i compile this with gcc i get an "cannot allocate an object of abstract type" error. Whereas when i replace

```
auto buffer=...
```

with

```
Derived& buffer=...
```

everything compiles fine. Why is that the case? Is auto not deducing the right type or something?

Also i found a dirty trick to still use auto:

```
void ThirdClass::demoMethod(Base& obj) {
    auto buffer=dynamic_cast<Derived*>(&obj);
    anotherMethod(*buffer);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `auto` deduces the type `Derived buffer`, not `Derived& buffer`.

Comment: What version of g++ are you using? Works fine to compile your code [after fixing trivial typos such as no return type on `demoMethod` and no inheritance on `derived`] - both clang++ 3.7 (about two weeks old) and g++ 4.9.2.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: If the missing return type is fixed, it fails in the reported way with whatever compiler ideone uses: http://ideone.com/UEtfui

Comment: @BillLynch: Always nice when the code changes between you trying it out and the next person trying it... ;)

Comment: @BillLynch: FYI, hover over "C++14" to see what compiler it uses (for the record, at time of writing it's GCC 4.9.2).

Comment: @BillLynch Use Coliru or Wandbox instead. Ideone is inferior to those in every respect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting `Derived` from `auto`. Use this instead:

```
auto & buffer = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

§7.1.6.4/7:

> When a variable declared using a placeholder type is initialized […]
>   the deduced return type or variable type is determined from the type
>   of its initializer. […] let `T` be the declared type of the variable
>   or return type of the function. **If the placeholder is the `auto`
>   type-specifier, the deduced type is determined using the rules for
>   template argument deduction.** […] obtain `P` from `T` by replacing the
>   occurrences of `auto` with either a new invented type template
>   parameter `U`[…]. **Deduce a value for `U` using the rules of template
>   argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1), where `P` is a
>   function template parameter type and the corresponding argument is the
>   initializer.**

So, in order to familiarize yourself with the process, take a look at the actual rule used for deducing the type of `buffer`: What happens if you change

```
template <typename U>
void f( U );
```

to

```
void f( Derived& );
```

when calling `f` with an lvalue of type `Derived`? Clearly, for the function template, `U` will be deduced as `Derived`, which then yields a deduction failure.
This directly corresponds to the deduction of the placeholder type in your example - `auto` will be replaced by `Derived`, and that fails, as `Derived` is abstract.

Generally speaking, if you write

```
auto obj = …;
```

**`obj` will never be a reference**, just as `U` will never be deduced as a reference type when calling the above function template.

---

Instead, use `auto&`:

```
auto& buffer = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(obj);
```

Now, `P` is `U&`:

```
template <typename U>
void f(U&);
```

`U` is, of course, still deduced as `Derived`, but the type of `P` - which is effectively the type of `buffer` - is `Derived&`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I figured that the asker is used to template argument deduction :)

Comment: @Columbo To be honest im not. I just started with c++ like 3 months ago and havent stumbled over templates yet.

Comment: @SuppenGeist In that case, nevermind. Maybe someone else will find this answer useful.